# Apache "authentication failure for "/": Password Mismatch"

Tags: apache

I am a newbie to Apache, using Apache 2.2.22. I am trying to password protect my whole localhost website using .htaccess; .htaccess is located in /Apache/htdocs and the password file is in /Apache/passwd. Trying to access the site I get prompted for a username/password but it always fails with the error (from error.log) `[error] [client 127.0.0.1] user myuser: authentication failure for "/": Password Mismatch`.

The password file was created with:

```
htpasswd -c /Apache/passwd/passwords myuser
```

My .htaccess file:

```
AuthType Basic 
AuthName "Restricted Files" 
AuthUserFile c:/Apache/passwd/passwords
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
require valid-user
```

My httpd.conf file was modifed with:

```
<Directory "C:/Apache/htdocs">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride AuthConfig
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The Apache doc for Authentication and Authroization states to make sure that the modules `mod_authn_core` and `mod_authz_core` have either been built into the httpd binary or loaded by the httpd.conf configuration file. But I don't know how to do this; they are not listed in the Modules section of my httpd.conf file. `mod_auth_basic.so`, `mod_authn_file.so`, and `mod_authz_groupfile.so` are loaded via the httpd.conf file.

Thank you for any help or ideas.

Comment: Run `apache2ctl -M` and check if the needed modules are present.